# "Lost data" after changing RAM quota in Couchbase Server

Tags: couchbase

I changed the “Index RAM Quota” from Couchbase Server 4.5.1-2845 Community Edition settings and now all the queries don’t find any data…
When I run “SELECT id FROM myBucket” I get 4 ids… The bucket contains thousands of documents, not just 4.

If I click on “Data Buckets” > “MyBucket” > “Documents” I see all the documents, but the queries seem broken.

Any ideas?!

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the bucket? What does a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myBucket` return (that's a query which doesn't use any indexes)

Comment: I have about 10 indexes (including the primary index), all of them have "ready" status and 100% initial build progress...

Comment: And the `SELECT COUNT(*)`?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this issue locally, and I'm not seeing the same problem. Are there any messages in the log that might indicate that the index service is having problems?

Comment: I see a "Control connection to memcached on 'ns_1@127.0.0.1' disconnected: {badmatch,{error,einval}}" error, but I don't know if it's relevant! Maybe it is!

Comment: I created a primary index again as Ramitha Kalana said in the answer below, I was able to see all the ids with a query, so SELECT COUNT(*) returns the right count... But... when I run SELECT * FROM myBucket WHERE id = "doc_id" I get "resultCount": 0

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to solve by adding a primary index to your bucket

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `bucket-name-primary-index` ON `bucket-name` USING GSI;
```

Comment: There is already a primary index...! Should I try to create it again?

Comment: I created a new primary index (with different name than the previous index) and the queries don't work as expected yet!